# Fast python implementation of cropping with padding=wrap

Tags: numpy, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I have a pretty long for loop where I crop images at different locations with a fixed size squared window to get numpy arrays.
I was using `crop` from `PIL` Image library. An then I convert it as a `numpy` array with `np.asarray`.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
im=Image.open("image.png")
box=(left,top,left+width,top+width)
res=np.asarray(im.crop(box))
```

However the only padding implemented (when the center of your crop is at less than width/2 of a border) is constant at 0 and I would like it to be "wrap" padding as in numpy pad doc.

My solution would be to do something like this.

```
array=np.asarray(Image.open("image.png"))
padded_array=np.pad(array,((width/2,width/2),(width/2,width/2),(0,0)),"wrap")
res=padded_array[top+width/2:top+width/2+width,left+width/2:left+width/2+width]
```

I was wondering if there was a more efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap over the edges using `numpy.take`, for example with a 3x3 cropping window:

```
a = numpy.arange(100).reshape((10,10))
a.take([8,9,10], mode="wrap", axis=1).take([9,10,11], mode="wrap", axis=0)
```

It also accepts lists of lists for indices, for instance two cropping windows:

```
b = a.take([[8,9,10],[3,4,5]], mode="wrap", axis=1).take([[9,10,11],[9,10,11]], mode="wrap", axis=0)
```

You can then recover the cropped windows:

```
window1 = b[0,:,0::2].reshape(3,3)
>>> array([[98, 99, 90],
           [ 8,  9,  0],
           [18, 19, 10]])
window2 = b[1,:,1::2].reshape(3,3)
>>> array([[93, 94, 95],
           [ 3,  4,  5],
           [13, 14, 15]])
```

For small windows, it might be efficient to do it this way, but for larger windows you might want to specify one set of indices at a time, in a loop.

Comment: Thanks ! I did not know this function. Not sure if it is really faster though, I am gonna check.

Comment: Depends on the number and size of the windows you are trying to take. The issue with using padding is that you may need to pad some windows but not others (some wrap around and some don't), and you need to pad the whole array for every window, which is inefficient in itself.

Comment: Yes good remark, I guess it boils down to the time the reshaping takes compared to useless padding.